# Can tf.keras.utils.get_file(), be used to load local zip files?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have zip file containing 4 image folders. The tutorial I followed on Google Colab uses a similar zip file but the file is hosted online and the link is given as the value of `origin` parameter which is necessary.I uploaded my zip file to Google Drive and can access it in Colab. Is it possible to load a local file using get_file()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently ran into this myself. After not finding answers, I had to put on the old thinking cap, and solved it.
So in the documentation for `tf.keras.utils.get_file()` it states the first two arguments are mandatory, the rest can default per internals. These are the FILENAME for reference and naming in the cache, and ORIGIN which *must* be a URL from where the image/data is obtained.

```
myFile = sys.args[1]  # just for example...
fullPath = os.path.abspath("./" + myFile)  # or similar, depending on your scenario
data_for_processing = keras.utils.get_file(myFile, 'file://'+fullPath)
```

`file://` is a URL for a local file trick.

Comment: The right answer but in a Jupyter notebook on Windows, of course, this only worked once I put the / the wrong way around to file:\\....

Answer (score 5):

If you have mounted your gdrive and can access your files stored in drive through colab, you can access the files using the path `'/gdrive/My Drive/your_file'`. For me, I needed to unzip the file, so I used

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(your_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
```

I used `'/content'` as the directory_to_extract_to.

Then you can access the data the usual way.

```
base_dir = '/content/my_folder'    

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
base_dir,
target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
subset='training')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is useful for unzip the file. For example:-

```
dataset_url='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz'
data_dir=keras.utils.get_file('folder_name',origin=dataset_url,cache_dir='.', untar=True)
```

where cache_dir-> tells you where it will be stored and untar-> is that you want unzip that file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the file:// keyword but you have to append a / if you are in Linux based system.

```
dataset_url = "file:///Users/isidoros/images.tar.gz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Images', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
```