# Changing dataset_url to local filepath in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working through the tensorflow classification tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification).

In the "download the dataset" section there is code to import the dataset_url:

```
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

I have my own image dataset on my Mac hardrive. How do I go about changing the filepath? I've tried to update the dataset_url with the filepath but it's creating an error message.

I'm getting a 0 when I run the following:

```
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count)
```

I have my images unzipped in separate folders but I don't seem to be able to allocate them correctly in python. The links provided didn't seem to work. Grateful for any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide the full error message you are getting.

Comment: Same problem solved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166043/can-tf-keras-utils-get-file-be-used-to-load-local-zip-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can tf.keras.utils.get\_file(), be used to load local zip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166043/can-tf-keras-utils-get-file-be-used-to-load-local-zip-files)

Answer (score 0):

Define the path where your images dataset resides till main folder name.

```
train_path='c:/../dataset/flowers' # I have already downloaded this dataset
```

then use "**image_dataset_from_directory**" to fetch images from that directory :

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory
    
data_dir= tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_path) # insert images directory path here
```

This will automatically detect images from subfolders and each subfolder name will be those images class name (label).

```
flowers/
  daisy/
  dandelion/
  roses/
  sunflowers/
  tulips/
```

Output:

```
Found 4317 files belonging to 5 classes.
```

You can find more details on this "**image_dataset_from_directory**" api [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) and can set its other parameters as per your requirement.